# Reading the Oracle Timestamp in Java and compare back

Tags: java, oracle, timestamp

From a Java program i want to query Min record Timestamp for a set of records from Oracle DB and then use it to update the record that had min Create Time Stamp

The time stamp is in the format 04-NOV-11 02.00.07.000000000 AM  in the table

When I read it in Java.sql.Timestamp it is read as 2011-11-04 02:00:07.0

and I am not able to use the update query with Create Time Stamp = 2011-11-04 02:00:07.0

Pls help in overcoming this

Comment: What's wrong with the update query? What happens?

Comment: When I do a select * from table where Create Time Stamp = 2011-11-04 02:00:07.0 in DB I am not getting any hit.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm. Matching timestamps is always a tricky thing but trying something like

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE time_column = TIMESTAMP '2011-11-04 02:00:07.0'`

on ORACLE 10 via JDBC works for me.

How are you executing the query?